# Problems with mouse zoom and ctrl button zoom

Tags: mouse

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm experiencing several problems with the zoom.-
For example:

- In firefox, if I press ctrl the page zoom in.
- When I open an image and I hover over the image with the mouse (without pressing any button) the image zoom out
- When I hover a gnuplot graph with the mouse (without pressing any button) the plot zoom out
- If I open a CAD geometrical model it zoom out when pressing ctrl.
  What can I do to solve this problem?
  Thanks,
  Nabla

Comment: I believe (I have not seen anything confirming this), since I'm seeing many posts about the 20.04 LTS missing a unified zoom in/out as in previous versions.